# ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/assets/javascripts

Tags: javascript, css, ruby-on-rails

I am running a development server and I'm trying to load some static pages and files (images, css and javasripts) in my rails application for testing. (In general, I'm new in rails. The Rails installation has been done on Linux subsystem in Windows 10).
Although I have placed the files in `assets/images`, `assets/javascripts` and `assets/stylesheets` I couldn't manage to read these files in my test apprication when server runs. I receive the following errors almost for all files I have added:

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/assets/javascripts/jquery.min.js"):

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/assets/javascripts/bootstrap.min.js"):

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/assets/javascripts/jqBootstrapValidation.js"):
```

and for images

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/assets/images/portfolio/dreams-preview.png"):
```

The same applies for some css files also (not all).

I tried several ideas I found here in order to solve this but I had no luck.
I tried to setup:

```
config.serve_static_files = true
```

in `development.rb` and

```
rake assets:precompile
```

Obviously, these files are not visible by rails application but I still don't understand what I have to do to make them visible. Can you please help me on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to include these files in **application.js** manully or just write `//= require_tree .` to load all js

Similarly, you have to work for css. Add  `*= require_tree .` in `application.css`.

Comment: Hey please edit your answer to `//= require_tree` . to `//= require_tree .`

Comment: @Chakreshwar Sharma. I have already checked these files and they have the correct settings, as you described, from very beginning.

Comment: @kirkos: check the source code of html page & search that whether these files are loaded or not

Comment: I also tried to call explicitly `//= require bootstrap.min`, the result is the same.

Comment: @Chakreshwar Sharma. In my html the call is like this `<script src="assets/javascripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>` or `<img src="assets/images/logos/designmodo.jpg" class="img-responsive img-centered" alt="">` . I checked in the browser console, It is not load the files

Comment: paste your html code where you are calling the js & css & the image

Comment: @Chakreshwar Sharma. I have only a single page in `homepage.html.erb` calling the above js and css. I can't split it in smaller pages. However, what is the point of this? I suppose it will find the js and image files if I make it `<script src="bootstrap.min.js"></script>` and `<img src="designmodo.jpg" class="img-responsive img-centered" alt="">` in the split pages. The problem is why it cannot find the path `assets/javascripts/` or `assets/images/`.

Comment: are u changing the layout?

Comment: use <%= javascript_include_tag "bootstrap.min" %> instead of <script src="bootstrap.min.js"></script>   Apply the same for css as well

Comment: For image use image tag like <%= image_tag("designmodo") %> http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper.html#method-i-image_tag

Comment: @Chakreshwar Sharma. I did what you suggest. But now I received an error page `Sprockets::Rails::Helper::AssetNotPrecompiled in Welcome#homepage`. The error page suggests to `Add Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( bootstrap.min.js ) to config/initializers/assets.rb and restart your server`. So I did it but the error is still there. @Moderator. Sorry, I don't have the required reputation to transfer this discussion to chat

Comment: Yes, a single page `homepage.html.erb`

Comment: This is not the correct way to include assets, use <%= javascript_inlcude_tag "file_name" %> for js & <%= stylesheet_link_tag "file" %> for css & then precompile them in asset.rb like Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += ['alljs.js','allcss.css']

Comment: For images should I use `<%= image_tag("designmodo", "image2", "image3".... etc) %>` as you suggest above?. And then, for precompilation, should I use `rake assets:precompile` or is not necessary since they are included in `assets.rb`? What about the calls for images in html? How should they change? Is the following OK?: `<img src="designmodo.jpg" class="img-responsive img-centered" alt="">`. What about the calls of js files in my html, should I completely remove them?

Comment: For each image , u have write like <%= image_tag("image1.png") %> , no need to run rake assest:precompile if u r working on development mode, For calling images in html , use above syntax as I suggested instead of plain html , replace the syntax for calling js & css as I suggested above

Comment: Thanks for your help, I followed your instructions but please see my edit above

Comment: You have done the spelling problem as the states, there is problem in include spelling, you have writen inluinlude instead of include, so update the syntax, it should work

Comment: I'm very sorry, that was a really stupid mistake. I was looking again and again on it and I couldn't see it!

Comment: In general, yes. Two conflicts for javascript functions were appeared in the console and two errors (`ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/assets/bootstrap.min.css.map"):` and `ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/assets/bootstrap.css.map"):`) for which I cannot see where is the problem. However the site works. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Upvoted! But it is not shown as I have reputation less than 15. However it is recorded.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, in order to resolve this error and transfer my static pages to Rails I had to modify my `homepage.html.erb` as follows:

*Stylesheet links*:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "bootstrap.min.css" %>
```

the following also works:

```
<link href="assets/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

*Javascript include*:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "bootstrap.min.js" %>
```

In general, I found that no precompilation is necessary. I tested and it works with or without precompilation.
The following also works:

```
<script src="assets/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

*Tag for images*:

```
<%= image_tag("portfolio/dreams-preview.png", class: "img-responsive img-centered") %>
```

Rails use by default the normal path for images (`assets/images`). The full path should not be used. Unless the path for images is different, use only the path deeper than `assets/images`, if exists.

No changes were made in `application.html.erb` but precompilation for javascripts and stylesheets is necessary in `assets.rb`:

```
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += ['agency.min.js', 'agency.min.css', ...]
```

Eventually the site works, although some conflicts in the execution of javascripts might be appear.