# No route matches [GET] "/javascripts/active_admin.js

Tags: ruby-on-rails

The error message is

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/javascripts/active_admin.js"):
  
actionpack (5.2.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:65:in `call'
web-console (2.3.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:28:in `block in call'
web-console (2.3.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:18:in `catch'
web-console (2.3.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:18:in `call'
actionpack (5.2.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:33:in `call'
railties (5.2.2.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
railties (5.2.2.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `block in call'
activesupport (5.2.2.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:71:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (5.2.2.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:28:in `tagged'
activesupport (5.2.2.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:71:in `tagged'
railties (5.2.2.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `call'
sprockets-rails (3.2.1) lib/sprockets/rails/quiet_assets.rb:13:in `call'
actionpack (5.2.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:81:in `call'
request_store (1.5.0) lib/request_store/middleware.rb:19:in `call'
actionpack (5.2.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:27:in `call'
rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/method_override.rb:24:in `call'
rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/runtime.rb:22:in `call'
activesupport (5.2.2.1) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:29:in `call'
actionpack (5.2.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:14:in `call'
actionpack (5.2.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:127:in `call'
rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:110:in `call'
webpacker (3.6.0) lib/webpacker/dev_server_proxy.rb:22:in `perform_request'
rack-proxy (0.6.5) lib/rack/proxy.rb:57:in `call'
railties (5.2.2.1) lib/rails/engine.rb:524:in `call'
puma (4.3.5) lib/puma/configuration.rb:228:in `call'
puma (4.3.5) lib/puma/server.rb:713:in `handle_request'
puma (4.3.5) lib/puma/server.rb:472:in `process_client'
puma (4.3.5) lib/puma/server.rb:328:in `block in run'
puma (4.3.5) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:134:in `block in spawn_thread'
Processing by ExceptionsController#show as */*
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 30ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms | MongoDB: 0.0ms)
```

The solutions mentioned in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40484739/actioncontrollerroutingerror-no-route-matches-get-assets-javascripts) doesn't work for me. I have been looking around here and there and could not find anything.

how do I solve this ?

Comment: Do you have `active_admin.js` file in javascripts folder ?
If not try with this command - `rails generate active_admin:assets`

Comment: @ts you are right. There is no `active_admin.js`. The command created only `active_admin.js.coffee` and `active_admin.scss`.

Comment: rename it `active_admin.js`

Comment: @ts I did. Thanks it worked.

Comment: I added this as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To generate active_admin assets run this command

```
rails generate active_admin:assets
```